# to give a column's data equal values divide by the Average (Mean) numbers in the series in R

Tags: r, equality

An easy function (for everyone) to give equal Values divide by the Average (Mean) instead of writing it out all the time every time I change the amount. In this example I have 5. But I might want more or less. Thanks. All add up to 1. I know I didn't explain it properly, but I hope you understand

```
Amount <- c(Coat=1/5,Boat=1/5,Shop=1/5,Car=1/5,Bike=1/5)
```

Lets say I have 5 series in a Column. I want the values in the column to be all equal (1/5). I want the Column to add up to 1.

```
sum(Amount) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether I understood correctly, but I think you want to transform a vector to retain the proportions but have a sum of exactly 1. The way to do this would be to divide the vector by its sum:

```
> amounts = c("car"=2,"bike"=2,"ship"=1)
> amounts = amounts/sum(amounts)
> amounts
 car bike ship 
 0.4  0.4  0.2
```

Is this what you were looking for?